# Why won't this trigger work using the inserted table, but will when replacing it with a manually created table?

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2012

My problem domain is one where a person may record the presence state (present, late or absent) of another person to an activity. Such recordings can be modified, but a version history is mantained.

I modeled it in a database with 4 tables: `Person`, `Activity`, `Registration` and `ObsoleteRegistration`. `Registration` has a foreign key (`activity`) for the `Activity` table, two foreign keys (`registrant` and `registree`) for the `Person` table, and a `state` column whose value can be `present`, `late` or `absent`. `ObsoleteRegistration` stores old versions of `Registration` records. (only the most recent registration for each `registree` / `activity` couple is stored inside `Registration`). Every table has an `id` column which acts as primary key.

Since queries asking for the total number of presences and absences to an activity are much more frequent than queries inserting registrations, I added the redundant `presences` and `absences` columns to the Activity table, and seek to keep them updated with a trigger. I came up with the following code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateActivitypresencestatistics
ON Registrations
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Activity
    SET
        presences = presences + Updates.presencesToAdd + Updates.absencesToBeConvertedInpresences,
        absences  = absences + Updates.absencesToAdd - Updates.absencesToBeConvertedInpresences
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            inserted.activity AS activity,
            SUM (CASE WHEN (Present.state IS NULL) AND (inserted.state = 'present' OR inserted.state = 'late') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS presencesToAdd,
            SUM (CASE WHEN (Present.state = 'absent') AND (inserted.state = 'present' OR inserted.state = 'late')THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS absencesToBeConvertedInpresences,
            SUM (CASE WHEN (Present.state IS NULL) AND (inserted.state = 'absent') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS absencesToAdd
        FROM Registrations AS Present
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN inserted
        ON 
            Present.registree = inserted.registree
            AND Present.activity = inserted.activity
        GROUP BY
            inserted.activity
    ) Updates
    WHERE 
        Activity.id = Updates.activity
END
```

It yields no errors (neither on creation, nor on trigger), but it doesn't seem to update the `presences` and `absences` columns as it should. (their value remains unchanged)

Surprisingly, however, replacing the `inserted` table with a manually created table containing the same data that the inserted table should contain on an insertion results in everything working correctly.

Is there any common mistake I'm making? Is there any way I can understand better what's going on behind the scenes?

If the details are insufficient, let me know, I can elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: as it often turns out, I was just doing stupid things out of tiredness.
The trigger would work perfectly if it was a BEFORE INSERT trigger: being that it checks for differences between the `Registration` and the `inserted` tables, it cannot work because in a AFTER INSERT trigger they are identical.

Of course, since SQL Server doesn't provide BEFORE INSERT triggers, it must be changed to an INSTEAD OF trigger, with the insertion implemented manually.

The following code works:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateActivitypresencestatistics
ON Registrations
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Activity
    SET
        presences = presences + Updates.presencesToAdd + Updates.absencesToBeConvertedInpresences,
        absences  = absences + Updates.absencesToAdd - Updates.absencesToBeConvertedInpresences
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            inserted.activity AS activity,
            SUM (CASE WHEN (Present.state IS NULL) AND (inserted.state = 'present' OR inserted.state = 'late') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS presencesToAdd,
            SUM (CASE WHEN (Present.state = 'absent') AND (inserted.state = 'present' OR inserted.state = 'late')THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS absencesToBeConvertedInpresences,
            SUM (CASE WHEN (Present.state IS NULL) AND (inserted.state = 'absent') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS absencesToAdd
        FROM Registrations AS Present
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN inserted
        ON 
            Present.registree = inserted.registree
            AND Present.activity = inserted.activity
        GROUP BY
            inserted.activity
    ) Updates
    WHERE 
        Activity.id = Updates.activity

    INSERT INTO Registrations
    SELECT registrant, registree, status, activity -- Explicit list necessary because of the identity primary key column
    FROM inserted
END
```

**Update:** this problem would not arise if the trigger could select records from the deleted table that UPDATE triggers can access, which suggests that it would be better off modeled as an UPDATE trigger. The above works, but making such change (and adjusting accordingly, e.g. making registree/activity a compound key) removed the problem and simplified the implementation.

If you are experiencing the same issue, consider using UPDATE query and triggers instead.

Comment: `deleted` table holds old values, `inserted` new ones. Use both to determine differences. This works in after trigger.

Comment: I was aware of that, the problem was that my approach was fundamentally wrong: I was trying to use an INSERT query as an UPDATE query. (this can't be seen from my question because I didn't mention some other triggers, having judged them irrelevant)
I made some minor adjustments (set registree/activity as compound key, and implemented auditing using another table to store old registrations) and then modeled my trigger again as an AFTER UPDATE, being able to use the deleted and inserted table, thus removing any need to access the actual table, and everything was smooth.